# iText: Successfully resize one page pdf, but fail when there are multiple pages in the pdf document

Tags: java, resize, itext

I need to resize every page in my pdf from letter to legal size. Here is what I got so far

```
 public void resize (float x, float y, float scale) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(pdfOut));
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Even though the resize is correct, the output pdf only contain 1 page. Any help please?

Comment: You're not incrementing the page on the new resized document, so all the pages you're loading from the original are going into the same single page on the new pdf. Should have a call to `.newPage();` in there somewhere.

Comment: @Marc B: can you show a bit more to me. I look at the documentation, `PdfImportedPage` does not have a constructor, so I am not sure how to create a new page.

Comment: @Marc B: I figure out what you means: It is `document.newPage()`. ohh man, if you could have said `document.newPage()` instead of `.newPage()`, you would have save me 2 hours of search around :D. Thanks man +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer. I need `doc.newPage()` in the loop, read `Marc B` comment on my original question for more information

```
public void resize (float x, float y, float scale) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(pdfOut));
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        doc.newPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've just implemented this technique successfully to resize pages but have a follow-up question: I had previously been using the PdfCopy class to copy the PDF but this seems approach seems to be no more code and can scale as well. Is PdfCopy doing anything clever that is missed out when I create the PDF in this way?

Comment: What is x,y and scale with example or post full source code i need this