# How to check whether a page in PDF is A4 or not

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am creating a small application in which I open a existing PDF and then check whether the individual pages are in A4 or not. If pages are not in A4 then convert them to A4.

I am facing two problems now:

1. How to check whether the page in PDF is in A4 or not?
2. During the conversion of a non-A4 page to A4, the text outside the A4 page frame is omitted. Therefore it cause some loss of content.

How can I get around these two issues?

Comment: another method for question 1... http://rory.streetfamily.info/PermaLink,guid,ddfebc2e-9b52-48e4-945d-9401c90d4c55.aspx

Comment: Concerning problem 2: you state a problem here but don't say what page manipulations would be acceptable in your case. E.g. if your page is in A4 landscape, is it ok to simply rotate the content? Or is rotation not an option and instead the landscape content has to be squeezed onto a portrait page? Is rescaling the page an option?

Comment: @naveen the method shown at that link assumes that all pages of the PDF have the same dimensions. This does not need to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

load file with `PdfReader` class.

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("path to your file");
 Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i); // i page number, index starts at 1
 for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
 {
      Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
      var a = rect.Width;
      var b = rect.Height;
 }
```

for A4 Portrait format variables should be `a == 595`, `b == 842`. There is small tolerance when talking about page dimensions.[More information.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)

I have a method like that:

```
public static bool CheckFirstPageSizeA4Portret(Document doc)
    {

        var a = doc.PageSize.Width;
        var b = doc.PageSize.Height;
        pageFormat format = PageFormat.GetPageFormat(a, b);
        if (format == pageFormat.A4_Portret)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

`pageFormat` is enum that static `PageFormat` class returns.
`PageFormat` class is quite long, but simple and posting here would be silly, its almost 500 lines long.
what class does, it checks if the given dimensions corresponds with any official A, B or C page format and returns the name of format.

For the second question look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179096/itext-successfully-resize-one-page-pdf-but-fail-when-there-are-multiple-pages) It's java code there, but I think you should get the idea.

Comment: Is the `Reader` class you use actually the iTextSharp `PdfReader` class? Furthermore your CheckFirstPageSizeA4Portret seems to imply that this is a method to use when creating a *new* document, the question was about checking an *existing* PDF. And the reference you give concerning the second question is sub-optimal as the code there drops all interactive features of the source document.

Comment: you are right, its `PdfReader` class. Function `PageFormat.GetPageFormat()` as parameter gets two float numbers, doesn't matter from where. You can combine it with the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

@masius already indicated in his answer how to retrieve the dimensions of a page using the `GetPageSizeWithRotation` method.

Please also take into account, though, that the dimensions returned by that method may actually be scaled by the **/UserUnit** entry of the page dictionary. The dimensions returned by `GetPageSizeWithRotation` are given in the **/UserUnit** value times 1 / 72 inch, and that value defaults to 1.0.

The solution presented in the answer to the question "iText: Successfully resize one page pdf, but fail when there are multiple pages in the pdf document" @masius refers to is somewhat suboptimal as it drops all interactive features (Acroform fields and other annotations).

I would propose extending the page mediabox to have an aspect ration as the A4 format and then scale the page using the **/UserUnit** page dictionary entry.