# how print pdf with page scaling c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, printing

i have an Winform application, its requirement is direct print any pdf document with taking printing setting Page Scaling as 'Shrink to printable area'.
is it possible .
how to set an option 'Page Scaling' in c# coding ?

Comment: PDF is not available out of the box; you need a third-party library for that. Personally, I have good experience with PdfSharp. It's free and is easy to use.

Comment: is Page Scaling option available in PdfSharp ?

Comment: I think it is possible. For example, take a look here: http://www.dib0.nl/code/295-scale-a-pdf-using-pdfsharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ViewerPreference` for "Scale to fit" in the PDF 1.7 spec.  You get `AppDefault` or `None`.  If you are the one doing the printing, you can always [call the extensive Acrobat API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html), but the client must be appropriately licensed.

You can, of course, look at any number of third party vendors to do the same.  I have had good success with Foxit in the past.  Take a look at their [Print Manager SDK](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/print-manager/).

If you know the size of the page you are to be printing on, you can always resize the PDF using iTextSharp or similar.  See [iText: Successfully resize one page pdf, but fail when there are multiple pages in the pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179096/itext-successfully-resize-one-page-pdf-but-fail-when-there-are-multiple-pages) as an example of how to do so.