# Resize and scale existing pdf into A4 size in itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I want to resize and scale the content into A4 size using itext (resize any size of pdf like A1,A2,A3..)

source link [iText: Successfully resize one page pdf, but fail when there are multiple pages in the pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179096/itext-successfully-resize-one-page-pdf-but-fail-when-there-are-multiple-pages/7181750)

I have tried this code but output pdf getting empty pages.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    resize(597.0,814.0,0.5f)
}

public void resize (float x, float y, float scale) throws Exception {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfIn);
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(pdfOut));
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        doc.newPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.addTemplate(page, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to check and change the scale and the x and y location for every page inside your `for` loop. You can't use the same scale for every page because it obviously will not work, also, what happens if pages have different orientations (landscape)?.

Comment: could you please help me with sample code

Comment: Have a go first and show which part you got stuck on. My comment tells you why it's not working and why you need to do to fix it. A great place to look would be your favourite search engine for terms like "itext7 get individual scale"

Comment: Try using `x=0` and `y=0` first.